# Can't figure out why this kernel build fails

Tags: android, linux, build, kernel

I'm trying to build a recovery for an Android device, but build fails with not too much (for me...) explanations. Here are the latest lines

```
target  C: libcrypto_static <= external/openssl/crypto/sha/sha1dgst.c
target  C: libcrypto_static <= external/openssl/crypto/sha/sha256.c
target  C: libcrypto_static <= external/openssl/crypto/sha/sha512.c
target  C: libcrypto_static <= external/openssl/crypto/sha/sha_dgst.c
target  C: libcrypto_static <= external/openssl/crypto/srp/srp_lib.c
make[2]: *** [vmlinux] Error 1
make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/Arch/javier/dati/download/part-tree/kernel-3.10'
make: *** [/home/Arch/javier/dati/download/part-tree/out/target/product/y991/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/arch/arm64/boot/Image.gz-dtb] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
target  C: libcrypto_static <= external/openssl/crypto/srp/srp_vfy.c

#### make failed to build some targets (12:24 (mm:ss)) ####
```

I can't put the whole output on pastebin because of its weight. Tell me which parts could be interesting for you.

EDIT:
At this link you can find last 5000 lines
http://pastebin.com/XAVNQJDY

Comment: Are you building your kernel with -j option (eg. make -j4)? In that case, you have to show more log lines.

Comment: Yes, I used -j5. I added a link with more output into the original question.

Comment: Maybe you should use another toolchain? Take a look here http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/help/solved-stock-kernel-build-problems-t2532147

Comment: It seems it's not my case. This is /proc/versions from stock rom
`Linux version 3.10.72+ (user@linux-user) (gcc version 4.9 20140514 (mtk-20150408) (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Dec 31 17:06:55 CST 2015`
and this is the toolchain shown by my build output
`CROSS_COMPILE=/home/Arch/javier/dati/download/part-tree/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android-`
same version.

Comment: Ok. I found the exact toolchain "flavour" used to build stock rom, but the error remains similar. How could I get a make output more explanatory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Thanks to the hint from @Adam I started the build with just one job to get a sequential output, and I found out that there were two problems just before the last lines

```
drivers/built-in.o:(.data+0x36980): undefined reference to `IMX135_MIPI_RAW_SensorInit'
```

drivers/built-in.o:(.data+0x369b0): undefined reference to `OV5648MIPISensorInit'
I set the correct sensors for my device in defconfig and built completed successfully.